# Can one set the default properties for new WinForms created in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, properties

Whenever I create a new WinForm, the FormBorderStyle defaults to Sizable. It'd be really convenient if I could config VS so that every new form I create has FormBorderStyle=FixedDialog (and similar with several other properties).

Does anyone know if VS allows you to alter the default properties?

Comment: You can make your own item template.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to create your own `Form template`, here are some steps to do it:

**Step 1:** Create your own form class in the current project by simply adding the default form to the project, then set the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog` in the `Properties window`. In this example, I named the form class **FixedDialogForm**.

**Step 2 :** Open the `Export Template` wizard window:

[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** Follow the instruction the complete the wizard, we have to choose the class file, the references to be included with the template, the icon of the template:

[image]

[image]

After all, you can add new form of your own template normally but with a notice that the template forms are under the group **My Templates**:

[image]