# How to update Templates?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, templates

Currently I'm creating a really big project in Visual Studio 2012, where there are some common settings for each form ("Cancel" and "Save" buttons, Methods that change in every form but have the same name, font sizes and types, form color etc.) it will save me a lot of time if I could do all the design a single windows form and when I edit or modify it, have the changes reflected in the other forms as well.

Let's say I need 10 forms, to create them I would choose this default format and have my menu and basic objects already placed and designed; then after 10 forms I decided to move a button a bit, but don't want to go to every form and move it; just change it in the original format, refresh and all my forms will have that button in the new location.

I used Templates as recommended by [Can one set the default properties for new WinForms created in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808317/can-one-set-the-default-properties-for-new-winforms-created-in-visual-studio). But I still have the issue that if I change something in the template it won't refresh in every other form created with the template to that point.

I've already thought of changing the InitializeComponent in the WinForm default format, but this is not recommended and I wouldn't want any errors from this later on.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is nothing you can do.  Once you use a template to create a project or a file, it becomes a one-off.

Comment: Have you looked at Visual Forms Inheritance?  Create your base form like you want it and then inherit all of your other forms from the base form?  It's just a class, so you can use inheritance, etc. with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance will work for your solution.

- Create "base" form with all "common" controls
- Create new "derived" form and change form to inherit from your "base" form.

If you have some common logic in base form, which need to be "overridden" in derived forms - put it to the virtual method

```
// Base form
protected virtual void Close()
{
    // Base logic
}

private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

// In derived form - just override "Close" method
protected override void Close()
{
   // custom logic - will be executed when "Close" button clicked
}
```

In base form leave empty space for custom controls. Because you will not be able access baseform controls through designer in derived form.

Another approach - Model-View-ViewModel(MVVM)
 - Introduce own `UserControl` with common controls(view) which have property - instance of ViewModel.(*Viewmodel will contains behaviour logic and possibility to change "base" settings.*)
 - Add this user control to all "derived" forms and set `UserControl.ViewModelProperty` to instance which will represent logic for this particular form.

Without knowing "full" context of your goals - difficult to suggest more, but I am pretty sure you can build maintainable relations between forms, which can share common logic and view.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing you can do.  Once you use a template to create a project or a file, it becomes a one-off.  You have to edit it manually, or use a text editor that is powerful enough to employ a find and replace with pattern matching and capture group insertion.

Comment: Is there anything else on VB that can do what I described?

Comment: Thank you I guess

Comment: Sometimes and answer is just an answer.  There isn't a desirable answer for everything.

Comment: @DhamarMartinez -  You can't use a template, but you can just create a base form and then inherit all the other forms from the base.  That might be an option.

Comment: I've tried that before, in that case the methods will all refer to the baseform to function, and in my case some buttons will have methods that depend on the location ("Save" is different in a form with 3 fields than in one with 10). By inheriting I can't modify at all the object except in the baseform.